# ToolStripButtons of a custom BindingNavigator appear locked in the Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, bindingnavigator

I'm trying to create a custom **BindingNavigator** control in with some extra ToolStripButton (`Edit` and `ExportToExcel`).
The ToolStripButton is added to the BindingNavigator, but I cannot select this new ToolStripButton, e.g., to add code in its Click event handler.   Actually, the ToolStripButtons appear *locked*.

Here is my code and an image that should describe the problem:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BindingNavigator : System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator
{
    public ToolStripButton btnEdit;
    public ToolStripButton btnExcelExport;

    public BindingNavigator()
    {
        this.LayoutCompleted += BindingNavigator_LayoutCompleted;
    }

    public void BindingNavigator_LayoutCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Items.Contains(btnEdit))
            return;
        if (this.Items.Count >= 11)
        {
            btnEdit = new ToolStripButton();
            btnEdit.Image = global::BaseControls.Properties.Resources.Edit___16x16;
            btnEdit.Name = "btnEdit";
            this.Items.Insert(10, btnEdit);

            this.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());

            btnExcelExport = new ToolStripButton();
            btnExcelExport.Image = global::BaseControls.Properties.Resources.Excel___16x16;
            btnExcelExport.Name = "btnExcelExport";
            this.Items.Insert(13, btnExcelExport);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: my bindingnavigator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BindingNavigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator) class has a dedicated Designer, [`BindingNavigatorDesigner`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Design/System/Windows/Forms/Design/BindingNavigatorDesigner.cs,11), derived from `ToolStripDesigner`.
The Designer calls the public virtual [AddStandardItems()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.addstandarditems) method, which is then called by Form Designer when a BindingNavigator is added to a Form.

To make your Buttons functional, override this method in a custom class and add new buttons here.
Now your ToolStripButtons are serialized in the Form Designer and, if you double-click one of your custom buttons, a `Click` handler is added to the Form.

Notes you can find in the .[Net Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingNavigator.cs,135):

> Override this method in derived classes to define additional or
> alternative standard items. To ensure optimal design-time support
> for your derived class, make sure each item has a meaningful value in
> its Name property. At design time, this will be used to generate a
> unique name for the corresponding member variable. The item's Name
> property will then be updated to match the name given to the member
> variable.

[image: BindingNavigator Custom]
<sub>As you can see, now the buttons are fully functional</sub>

I suggest you modify your custom BindingNavigator like this:

▶ Don't name your Custom Control `BindingNavigator`

```
public class BindingNavigatorEx : BindingNavigator
{
    private ToolStripItem btnEdit;
    private ToolStripItem btnExcelExport;

    public BindingNavigatorEx() { }

    public override void AddStandardItems()
    {
        base.AddStandardItems();
        Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());

        btnEdit = new ToolStripButton() {
            Image = Properties.Resources.Edit___16x16,
            Name = "bindingNavigatorButtonEdit",
            DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
        };
        Items.Add(btnEdit);

        btnExcelExport = new ToolStripButton() {
            Image = Properties.Resources.Excel___16x16,
            Name = "bindingNavigatorButtonExcelExport",
            DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image
        };
        Items.Add(btnExcelExport);
    }
}
```